# Oracle SQL: Restart sequence based on row

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence, gaps-and-islands

My dataset is as following:

```
**series**
start
continue
continue
end
start
continue
end
```

I need to add a column which contains a sequence ('leeftijd_seq') that starts at 'start', increments by 1 at 'continue' and ends at 'end'. I've tried te code below but my execute statement doesn't work for the sequence I've created.

```
SELECT batchnr, series,
  CASE WHEN series = 'start' THEN execute 'alter sequence leeftijd_seq restart start with 1;' and leeftijd_seq.nextval
    when series = 'continue' then leeftijd_seq.nextval
    ELSE leeftijd_seq.currval
    END SEQ_NO
FROM data order by batchnr asc
```

Comment: What if there is an "end" that is not followed by a "start", but by a "continue" for example, which behavior do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reads like a gaps-and-islands problem. I would suggest a window count of "start"s to build the groups:

```
select t.*,
    row_number() over(partition by grp order by batchnr) as seq_no
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(case when series = 'start' then 1 else 0 end) over(order by batchnr) as grp
    from mytable t
) t
```